# Change to Activity from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm new to Android programming. I have the question, that how i can intent from fragment to an activity.
I was trying to code it, but i failed :( ('l_places' is the layout of Fragment Places, and 'p_tr_fr' is a clickable TableRow)
Here's my code of the Fragment:

```
package com.fragment.toactivity;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class Places extends Fragment{


 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.l_places, container, false);//l_places is the layout
     return rootView;
 }

public void goToAttract(View v)
{
    if (v.getId()== R.id.p_tr_fr) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Listact.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
   public View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

};
}
```

and here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffd4d4d4">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffffff">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                style="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/p_tr_fr"
                android:onClick="onClick">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:src="@drawable/m_pf"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="@string/s_shop"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the TableRow, the app stops. Please help!
(sorry for my english)

Comment: I forgot to write, Listact's layout is empty, so i think the error wouldn't be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), BookmarkActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

@NAP code should work fine. If app stops - give us the stack trace?
Possible reason is that your activity is not declared in AndroidManifest.

you should have something like

```
<activity android:name="yourpackage.Listact" />
```

between `<application>` tag

Comment: I really don't know what's the problem, but it still won't work, although I changed my code to @NAP's code, and Manifest file also doesn't have any problems, I think:

Comment: <activity
            android:name="package.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="package.Listact"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_listact" >
        </activity>